# Do only top-level controls show up in the aspx.designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a simple aspx page and I add some labels and textboxes and a repeater to it, they will show up in the asp.designer.cs file, right?  Do labels and other controls inside a repeater show up in the designer or are they just for top-level controls.  I added a label to a repeater and I didn't see it in the designer, so I tried to add it manually, but everytime I did a build, it would remove it from the designer file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it the designer file only shows top level controls... the controls inside templates for data controls such as the repeater don't exist until run-time.